# How do I do a diff between rows in a table

Tags: mysql

I need to compare the values of rows between similar tables in different databases. How do I know which rows are different.

e.g. `db1.foo (contains 2000 rows) and db2.foo (contains 2003 rows)`. These 2 tables are supposed to be similar and I would like to know how to find the rows which are supposed to be additions. Note: Even the primary key ids in these tables are supposed to be the same.

I don't have access to any GUI tools and would like to know if there is any SQL command which I can use to perform this diff?

Answer (score 0):

Depending the check on the Primary Keys only:

```
    SELECT
        'a' AS DataOnlyInTable
      , a.*
    FROM
        db1.foo AS a
      LEFT JOIN 
        db2.foo AS b
          ON b.PK = a.PK
    WHERE b.PK IS NULL
UNION ALL 
    SELECT
        'b' AS DataOnlyInTable
      , b.*
    FROM
        db1.foo AS a
      RIGHT JOIN 
        db2.foo AS b
          ON b.PK = a.PK
    WHERE a.PK IS NULL
```

Depending the check on the whole rows:

```
    SELECT
        'a' AS DataOnlyInTable
      , a.*
    FROM
        db1.foo AS a
      LEFT JOIN 
        db2.foo AS b
          ON (b.PK, b.column2, b.column3, ...) 
           = (a.PK, a.column2, a.column3, ...)
    WHERE b.PK IS NULL
UNION ALL 
    SELECT
        'b' AS DataOnlyInTable
      , b.*
    FROM
        db1.foo AS a
      RIGHT JOIN 
        db2.foo AS b
          ON (b.PK, b.column2, b.column3, ...) 
           = (a.PK, a.column2, a.column3, ...)
    WHERE a.PK IS NULL
```